# Why FastText is not handling finding multi-word phrases?

Tags: nlp, fasttext

FastText pre-trained model works great for finding similar words:

```py
from pyfasttext import FastText
model = FastText('cc.en.300.bin')
model.nearest_neighbors('dog', k=2000)

[('dogs', 0.8463464975357056),
 ('puppy', 0.7873005270957947),
 ('pup', 0.7692237496376038),
 ('canine', 0.7435278296470642),
 ...
```

However, it seems to fail for multi-word phrases, e.g.:

```py
model.nearest_neighbors('Gone with the Wind', k=2000)

[('DEky4M0BSpUOTPnSpkuL5I0GTSnRI4jMepcaFAoxIoFnX5kmJQk1aYvr2odGBAAIfkECQoABAAsCQAAABAAEgAACGcAARAYSLCgQQEABBokkFAhAQEQHQ4EMKCiQogRCVKsOOAiRocbLQ7EmJEhR4cfEWoUOTFhRIUNE44kGZOjSIQfG9rsyDCnzp0AaMYMyfNjS6JFZWpEKlDiUqALJ0KNatKmU4NDBwYEACH5BAUKAAQALAkAAAAQABIAAAhpAAEQGEiQIICDBAUgLEgAwICHAgkImBhxoMOHAyJOpGgQY8aBGxV2hJgwZMWLFTcCUIjwoEuLBym69PgxJMuDNAUqVDkz50qZLi',
  0.71047443151474),
```

or

```py
model.nearest_neighbors('Star Wars', k=2000)
[('clockHauser', 0.5432934761047363),
 ('CrônicasEsdrasNeemiasEsterJóSalmosProvérbiosEclesiastesCânticosIsaíasJeremiasLamentaçõesEzequielDanielOséiasJoelAmósObadiasJonasMiquéiasNaumHabacuqueSofoniasAgeuZacariasMalaquiasNovo',
  0.5197194218635559),
```

Is it a limitation of FastText pre-trained models?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of FastText having any special ability to handle multi-word phrases.

So I expect your query is being interpreted as one long word that's not in the model, which includes many character n-grams that includes `' '` space characters.

And, as I don't expect the training data had any such n-grams with spaces, all such n-grams' vectors will be arbitrarily-random collisions in the model's n-gram buckets. Thus any such synthesized out-of-vocabulary vector for such a 'word' is likely to b even noisier than the usual OOV vectors.

But also: the `pyfasttext` wrapper is an abandoned unofficial interface to FastText that hasn't bee updated in over 2 years, and has a message at its PyPI page:

> Warning! pyfasttext is no longer maintained: use the official Python binding from the fastText repository: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python

You may find better results using it instead. See its `doc/examples` folder for example code for examples of how its can be queried for nearest-neighbors, and also consider its `get_sentence_vector()` as a way to split a string into words whose vectors are then averaged, rather than just treating the string as one long OOV word.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [documentation](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html#tokenization), official fastText unsupervised embeddings are built after a phase of tokenization, in which the words are separated.

If you look at your model vocabulary (`model.words` in the official python binding), you won't find *multi-word phrases* containing spaces.

Therefore, as pointed out by gojomo, the generated vectors are synthetic, artificial and noisy; you can deduce it from the result of your queries.

In essence, **fastText official embeddings are not suitable for this task**.
In my experience this does not depend on the version / wapper used.