# How does pre-trained FastText handle multi-word queries?

Tags: nlp, fasttext

Using the pre-trained model:

```
import fasttext.util
fasttext.util.download_model('en', if_exists='ignore')  # English
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
```

Checking `ft.words` there aren't entries with spaces or _ in it, but if I query the model with multi-words (e.g. `ft["get up"]`) it returns a vector without any error.
What does it do? Is it correct or should it be better to avoid these kind of queries?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575990/why-fasttext-is-not-handling-finding-multi-word-phrases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastText can synthesize a guess-vector, from word-fragments, for any string.

It can work fairly well for typo or variant word-form of a word that was well-represented in training.

For your 'word', `'get up'`, it might not work so well. There may have been no, or no-meaningful, character-n-grams in the training set of substrings of your 'word' like `'get '`, `'et u'`, or `'t up'`. But as FastText uses a collision- and presence- oblivious hash-table for storing the n-gram vectors, these will still return essentially-random vectors.

If you want instead something based on the per-word vectors for `'get'` and `'up'`, I think you'd want to use the `.get_sentence_vector()` method, instead:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/README.md#model-object

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I have another doubt now: if I run `ft.get_word_vector('get')` and `ft.get_sentence_vector('get')` I obtain two different vectors, while I thought there shouldn't be any difference since the sentence_vector function actually shouldn't split anything. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm unsure why those would vary. Can you check if perhaps they're just different-magnitude? (That is, their cosine-similarity remains 1.0.) And: does the vector from `model.get_word_vector('get')` match the one from `model['get']`? (Perhaps: the named method only retrieves the full-word vector learned during training, and could give an error for a missing word, while the more-compact-and-idiomatic `[…]`-access does the full usual combination of word+n-grams, and thus never gives an error for a missing-word.)

Comment: I checked with the magnitude issue and you were right! The cosine similarity between `model.get_word_vector('get')` and `model.get_sentence_vector('get')` is 1.0. Regarding the `model.get_word_vector('get')` and `model['get']` vectors, they are absolutely identical, checking with cosine similarity but also with ==. Thank you very much!

Comment: YW! (It thus seems that `get_sentence_vector()`, as part of its usual summing-of-multiple-word-vectors, performs some magnitude normalization that doesn't happen the other path.)